# PHP error - function redeclared form only on edit

Tags: nodes, 6

I'm using Drupal 6. I don't know why but, since three days ago, I can't edit nodes with PHP filter that creates forms (using forms api). I get the next PHP error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare form_all_node_type() (previously declared in .../includes/common.inc (1769) : eval()'d code:12) in ../includes/common.inc (1769) : eval()'d code on line 25, referer: ....
```

I can edit any other nodes, but if the node has PHP filter and It creates a form (using form api), I can't edit it. I have checked it with all nodes that creates forms. Although, if you navigate to the node, the form runs good without error. The problem is only when editing the node. If the node has PHP filter but It doesn't create forms, I can edit it.

I have read this post ["redeclare error"](https://www.drupal.org/node/72099) on drupal web, but It doesn't apply to my question.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I'll try to be more accurate. When I navigate to the node, the form is created, then thouse functions aren't redeclared, and the form is rendered.
Where is the difference when editing? I guess when I'm editing, thouse functions aren't running code, then It should be only text. Then, why I get this error?
Is there any db table I should truncate?